# Populate Field With Anchor Tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to populate a simple input field when you click on an anchor tag?

So something like this:

```
<a href="#">Click Here To Populate Field</a>

<input type="text" name="your-name">
```

Comment: Yes. What do you want to populate it with? What have you tried? This will also require JavaScript.

Comment: Links are for navigation between pages (or anchors). `button`s are for immediate actions in the same page. [Links are not buttons](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using jquery. You didn't say what you wanted to populate it with though

```
<a id="myTag" href="#">Click Here</a>
<input type="text" name="your-name">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTag a").click(function() {
        $("#your-name").val("the value");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, had to change a few things around. Not sure why I got negative votes :/